# Authentication handler in .NET Core 2.2 can not access claims which were set by another authentication handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity

I have custom authentication handler (`AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>`), which does authentication from custom cookie. This cookie contains user ID and another user information. So this handler does some decryption with some logic to parse cookie and extract all data.

Then I have another authentication handler, which should fetch all user roles. And this handler needs user ID, which is set by first handler. However when I try to access claims, there are none.

```
protected async override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{
    var allClaims = this.Context.User.Claims;
    var userId =    allClaims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var identity =  this.Context.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault();
    var claims2 = identity.claims;
    var userId2 =   identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
}
```

`allClaims` count is `0`.
`userId`  is `null`.
`identity` is from the first authentication handler, it's not `null`. But  `claims2` count is `0`.

I can see all claims in controller later on.

I could duplicate decryption logic from first handler, but it does not feel right.

So how do I access claims from another handler during this authentication process?

Answer (score 0):

In first AuthenticationHandler , you should build the claims , put them in `AuthenticationTicket` and returned :

```
protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{

    var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "nanyu") };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
    return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
}
```

You can  write a custom middleware that manually calls AuthenticateAsync() and creates a ClaimsPrincipal containing all the identities you need :

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();

    var result1 = await context.AuthenticateAsync("MyScheme");
    if (result1?.Principal != null)
    {
        principal.AddIdentities(result1.Principal.Identities);
    }

    var result2 = await context.AuthenticateAsync("MyScheme2");
    if (result2?.Principal != null)
    {
        principal.AddIdentities(result2.Principal.Identities);
    }

    context.User = principal;

    await next();
});
```

Config the authentication :

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "MyScheme";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "MyScheme";
})
.AddCustomAuth(o => { }).AddCustomAuthTwo(o => { });
```

`CustomAuthExtensions.cs`:

```
public static class CustomAuthExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCustomAuth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<CustomAuthOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        return builder.AddScheme<CustomAuthOptions, CustomAuthHandler>("MyScheme", "MyAuth", configureOptions);
    }
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddCustomAuthTwo(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<CustomAuthOptionsTwo> configureOptions)
    {
        return builder.AddScheme<CustomAuthOptionsTwo, CustomAuthHandlerTwo>("MyScheme2", "MyAuth2", configureOptions);
    }
}
```